# allow only specific ip addresses to connect to server using Maven -> Jetty

Tags: maven, jetty

EXPLANATION:

I want to block most incomming connections to my development server. I am working with a Maven project using the Jetty plugin.

The current setup requires running the project with 'mvn jetty:run -Pdev'. This starts a server and listens to any connections on the specified port. Here is the connector setup in pom.xml

```
<connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector">
    <port>1111</port>
    <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
</connector>
```

Blocking all external connections was fairly simple:

```
<connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector">
    <host>localhost</host>
    <port>1111</port>
    <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
</connector>
```

This does a good job of closing down access to external connections. This is perfect unless I need to test out the server from a virtual machine.

QUESTION:

I am looking for a simple way to specify allowable ip addresses to connect to my dev server. Ideally, it would look something like this: (I didn't see anything like this in the docs)

```
<connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector">
    <port>1111</port>
    <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
    <allowableIP>192.168.1.111</allowableIP>
    <allowableIP>192.168.1.112</allowableIP>
    <allowableIP>192.168.1.113</allowableIP>
</connector>
```

It doesn't need to be that easy, but I would prefer that the configuration be limited to the project (not the individual machine), so that the change will automatically effect all developers on my team.

OTHER INFO:

Other options:

```
1) remove the host line from the pom.xml file when access from a virtual machine is required
2) set up the firewall to only allow connections from specific ip addresses
3) do some virtual machine network configurations
```

the docs I used are here: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

It won't be that easy. You have to use the IPAccesshandler to define whilelisted and blacklisted IPs

You can have an example on how to implement it here: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/ipaccess-handler.html